# Error When Using java.awt.FileDialog on mac

Tags: java, macos, awt

When I try to use java.awt.Filedialog on Mac.
This comes in console:

```
objc[13803]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fffa61213d8) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride (0x157538f50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

What and Why is this error coming?

Comment: AWT in the GUI is over. Use Swing or JavaFX

Comment: No, I want to Use Native Components, So I am Using AWT, And Also This Type of Error also comes when using file chooser in python tkinter.

Comment: *"What and Why is this error coming?"* Given AWT is so old, I doubt Oracle is paying much attention to any parts of AWT not underlying Swing (I.E. the vast majority of AWT components). So I agree with @g00se. Use Swing of Java-FX. If you want to pursue it, search the [Bug Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/) for similar problems, and if none found, raise a new report (and watch Oracle not care about it).